# Уведомление при заряде MacBook выше 90%

Tags: macos, apple, автоматизация, push-уведомления

На айфоне есть возможности создать автоматизацию "Когда заряд аккумулятора поднимается выше 90%"=>выводить уведомление
[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Функция очень удобная, однако на MacBook так просто сделать не получилось. Если кто-то подскажет решение буду очень благодарен.

Comment: Лол. Но вы справились в итоге?

Comment: Нет. Я как раз спрашиваю как это возможно сделать

Comment: На маке попробуйте Automator